# How can i generate custom exe for each customer

Tags: python, c#, c++, asp.net, vb.net

So, the question i have is i have an vb.net application that will connect to my rest api. In order to connect though, it needs to know the customer id and token.

As this software will be deployed on thousands of pc's, i would love for a customer to be able to download a custom exe that contains the customer id and token automatically so it can be deployed via Group policy or RMM tool.

SO my question is, how can i have it that when a customer signs up on my website, my website will generate the custom exe for them with their user id and token?

I know many sites do this, especially RMM tools etc...basically creates an agent that connects back automatically.

I don't care what language what technology, etc. Just need to wrap my head around how to do this.

Comment: You can generate a file that will contain customer specific data and make it part of the build. This can be a header file for C++ that is included and used in some CPP file. Then you build, sign and package the executable and provide a download link for the customer. You have to store customer specific data in your database for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate those elements and store then in the .config file and when your customer will run his .exe verify those element, and if the one in your db is equal to the .config one's so your customer will be able to connect

Comment: So i'm thinking about just renaming the exe <token>.exe Then when it's ran, just parse the filename for the token needed....Good idea, bad idea?

Comment: I guess most people could counfound it as a malware if they opened their task manager. I think those sensitive value should be located inside a config file. Or add a login form.